# Flask application (with jinja2) won't render the template that I want (method problems?)

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

- I'm working on a simple flask application that displays a basic form with user, pass, verify pass, and email. The way I have it right now, if there are no errors, instead of going to the page i tell it to (welcome.html), it just goes back to my home page (index.html). There are comments in the code to guide you through it. Please help I've been racking my brain and the internet and trying lots and lots of things for the past week, and i need this for school or else im gonna fail. Here is my application code:

  ```
  from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template
  import jinja2
  import cgi

  app = Flask(__name__)

  app.config['DEBUG'] = True

  @app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
  def index():
      return render_template("index.html")

  #if my form makes a post request at the route / (as defined in the form in the index page), then go to index again, or welcome page
  @app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
  def welcome():
      username = str(request.form.get('username-actual'))
      password = str(request.form.get('password-actual'))
      verifiedpassword = str(request.form.get('verifedpassword-actual'))
      email = str(request.form.get('email-actual'))

      #if (not username) or len(username) < 3 or len(username) > 20 or ' ' in username: IGNORE THIS

      #If any of the fields have any of these conditions, fill the error message with the message. otherwise, empty

      if username == '' or len(username) < 3 or len(username) > 20 or ' ' in username:
          usererror = "Invalid username lol"
      else:
          usererror = ""

      if password == '' or len(password) < 3 or len(password) > 20 or ' ' in password:
          passworderror = "Invalid password lol"
      else:
          passworderror = ""

      if verifiedpassword != password:
          verifiedpassworderror = "Passwords dont match lol"
      else:
          verifiedpassworderror = ""

      if email == '' or len(email) < 3 or len(email) > 20 or ' ' in email or '@' not in email:
          emailerror = "Invalid email lol"
      else:
          emailerror = ""

      #if any of the error messages are not empty (meaning there are error messages), render the home page again, with the necessary strings provided for jinja
      if len(usererror) > 0 or len(passworderror) > 0 or len(verifiedpassworderror) > 0 or len(emailerror) > 0:
          return render_template("index",usererror=usererror,
                              passworderror=passworderror,
                              verifiedpassworderror=verifiedpassworderror,
                              emailerror=emailerror,
                              username=username,
                              email=email,)
      #otherwise, go to the welcome page, with the necessary username
      else:  
          return render_template("welcome.html",username=username)

  app.run()
  ```
- and here is my two form, index.html and welcome.html, respectively:

  ```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>
          User Sign-up
      </title>
      <style>
          .error { color:red; }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Sign-up</h1>
      <br>
      <form action="/" method="post">

          <div>
              <label>Username:  <input type="text" name="username-actual" value="{{username}}"></label> 
              <p class="error">{{usererror}}</p>
          </div>

          <div>
              <label>Password:  <input type="password" name="password-actual"></label>
              <p class="error">{{passworderror}}</p>
          </div>

          <div>
              <label>Verify Password:  <input type="password" name="verifiedpassword-actual"></label>
              <p class="error">{{verifypassworderror}}</p>
          </div>

          <div>
              <label>Email (optional):  <input type="text" name="email-actual" value="{{email}}"></label>
              <p class="error">{{emailerror}}</p>
          </div>

          <div>
              <input type="submit" name="sign-up-submit" value="Sign Up!">
          </div>

      </form>

  </body>
  </html> <p></p>
  ```
- Here is my welcome.html:

  ## Welcome, {{username}}!

Comment: I don't clearly understand your problem. Is it that, it keeps keeps going back to `index.html` after form submission?

Comment: i didn't get what your error is.

Comment: yes, after i submit the form it goes right back to the index.html whether there are error messages or not or not. also, one of my comments didnt express the code, i changed it.

Comment: So this may not exactly speak to your issue, but in stead of measuring your error messages as > 0, you could just place the entire function inside of a "try" block and then do "except Exception as e: return render_template(welcome.html)"  Also, for future reference it would be better to use WTForms or even client side form validation to check for @ signs and form length instead of using tons of logic in your views. I hope that makes sense :)